# Android Java Text File to Array

Tags: java, android, arrays

Good day,

I'm trying to convert items in Android from a Text File into an Array. So far, I'm all happy, as I can write to the Text File, and Read into the array. Here comes the issue.

I'm trying to write the items from the array into a ListView. I'm however not having any luck with writing the array list items into a list view.

I have an array called ShopsArray. I call eh array as follow:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter (this, R.layout.list_item, ShopsArray);
```

For some odd reason his just doesn't work however. It opens the GUI, and before displaying he array, it just crashes.

**LogCat:**

```
04-07 19:33:57.285: D/AndroidRuntime(18824): Shutting down VM
04-07 19:33:57.285: W/dalvikvm(18824): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42066ba8)
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824): Process: com.example.shoplisttest, PID: 18824
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shoplisttest/com.example.shoplisttest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at com.example.shoplisttest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:192)
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-07 19:33:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(18824):    ... 11 more
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Too much Text to copy an paste. Pasted it here: http://textuploader.com/tdml

Comment: Which line is the 192th line in `MainActivity.java` class?

Comment: `Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
  btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub`

Comment: Then please, post `MainActivity` layout XML.

Comment: http://textuploader.com/tdmh - Not enough space for code

Comment: your XML is ok...please, post `MainActivity` code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a snippet from working code, since you haven't really posted a lot of your code, hopefully looking at this will give you some indication of where your issue lies.

```
listDescItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        String items = loadFile(PATH + "/" + "items.txt");
        String[] sec = items.split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i < sec.length; i++) {
            String[] secd = sec[i].split("\\|");

            if (sec[i].trim().length() > 2) {

                String s0 = secd[0];
                String s1 = secd[1];
                String s2 = secd[2];
                String s3 = secd[3];

                listDescItems.add(s1);
            }

        }

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listDescItems));
```